# Being at Google's Mercy: A Tool for Webmasters

Tags: google, seo

you know what i would love? a tool by Google that tells you what they think of your site. if you're doing anything wrong that they are punishing you for or something. does such a tool exist?

Comment: You want to know why you are getting the page rank that you have?

Comment: Do you know about http://webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Comment: http://www.google.com/webmasters

Answer (score 10):

What about Google Webmaster Tools: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Once you verify that you're the proper owner of the site, it gives a bunch of information about how well your site is indexed, ranked, if there were errors with the crawling, etc.

Answer (score 1):

They punish people for trying to game the system. Just make a good website, try to be the best at what you do, be consistent in your publishing and Google will reward you.

Getting good traffic to a website is not hard. Getting them to buy is hard.